# Makefile doesn't match obj file

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have to work in a C project and i have problem with the make. The file structure is:

```
 dir
 --/bin
 --/src
     all the sources files (.c)
 --/includes
     all the includes (.h)
 makefile
```

makefile is:

```
CC   = gcc
RES  = 
_OBJ  = paciente.o utils.o obrasocial.o pacienteobrasocial.o orm.o 
profespecialidad.o profesional.o especialidad.o turnos.o $(RES)
LINKOBJ  = main.o utils.o $(RES)

MAINOBJ = main.o
MAINSRC= main.c

LIBS =  -L"/usr/lib"

IDIR =/includes

INCS = -I$(IDIR)
BIN  = tpfinalc

_DEPS = config.h utils.h
DEPS = $(patsubst %,$(IDIR)/%,$(_DEPS))

ODIR=/bin

CFLAGS = $(INCS) $(LIBS) -lpq
RM = rm -f

OBJ = $(patsubst %,$(ODIR)/%,$(_OBJ))

SDIR = /src
_SRC =  especialidad.c obrasocial.c orm.c paciente.c 
pacienteobrasocial.c profesional.c profespecialidad.c turnos.c utils.c
SRC = $(patsubst %,$(SDIR)/%,$(_SRC))

VPATH = src

.PHONY: all all-before all-after clean clean-custom

all: all-before tpfinalc all-after clean

$(BIN): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LINKOBJ) -o tpfinalc $(CFLAGS)

$(ODIR)/$(MAINOBJ): MAINSRC $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c MAINSRC -o $(ODIR)/$(MAINOBJ) $(CFLAGS)

$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

I guess that this should'be correct, but when I make my c files the console indicates that there isn't any rule to build bin/paciente.

Anyone have an idea why? Thanks You.

Answer (score 0):

One error is that `/includes` is an absolute path which does not exist (same applies to all other paths here). What you need is a relative path: `includes` or, if you like typing, `./includes`.

Another error is that you omit paths in the dependencies and rules, so that make never finds your files. E.g.:

```
$(ODIR)/%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

Should really be:

```
bin/%.o: src/%.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

All paths should be relative to the current directory, which is where your `makefile` is.